# Teamcity 2018.1. Cannot find a method to deploy a .war artifact to MS Azure/Tomcat in the build script

Tags: java, azure, teamcity, tomcat8

We are an small existing Java/Web development team using IJ Idea and CI/Hudson with Maven to auto deploy artifacts to on-premise IBM Websphere for several years.

Recently we migrated new applications to MS Azure/Tomcat and found we were unable to upload Web apps to Azure because of corporate proxy/firewalls so we resorted to using the Azure manual upload/ deploy mechanisms.

We are currently evaluating TeamCity (in both a Linux VM on Azure and the Azure Teamcity deploy script) and have been progressing well with the usual GIT build/deploy/release to Nexus steps.

Unfortunately I have hit a blocker when I come to try and deploy a .war artifact to Azure/Tomcat for CI (and production)

We have downloaded all the available Azure plugins for TeamCity (and we are deploying to Azure successfully on our Jenkins evaluation using the Azure App Service plugin)

Comment: war deploy - is just copying artifact into tomcat/webapp folder. why you can't use SCP ?  also there are different ways to deploy including maven+tomcat plugin : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Comment: Thanks for your response I will have a read. I think I must apologise for the lack of clarity in my request for help. The key aspect I forgot to say was that I was try to deploy to Azure/Tomat as a SaaS so need to use Azure Plugins or Cmdlets.
Anyway in the meantime I have got a basic MS PowerShell script working as a TeamCity build step to download the artifact from Nexus 3 and deploy to Azure Tomcat. It's not pretty and may not represent current 'best practices' but is good enough to demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
Build Step
Runner Type: PowerShell
Script source
-------------

$nexususername = 'admin'
$nexuspassword = 'adminPassword'

$username = '$AZUREUSER'
$password = 'AzurePassword'
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

$apiUrl = 'https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/webapps/'
$filePath = '/home/teamcity/deploy/'

$nexusUrl = 'http://yoursite.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8081/repository/your-releases/your/path/to/sample-web/2.2/sample-web-2.2.war'

$nexussecpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $nexuspassword -AsPlainText -Force
$nexuscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($nexususername, $nexussecpasswd)

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $secpasswd)

Write-Host ('>>> Start Downloading File from nexus')
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $nexusUrl -Credential $nexuscredential -Method Get -Outfile $filePath\sample-web.war
Write-Host ('>>> End Downloading File from nexus')


Write-Host ">>> Start Uploading WAR File"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl'sample-web.war' -Credential $credential -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication -UserAgent $userAgent -Method Put -InFile $filePath\sample-web.war -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
Write-Host ">>> Finish Uploading WAR File"
```